# Integrals of the type $\int\frac{dx}{\left(a^2+x^2\right) \sqrt{a^2+b^2+x^2}}$

Tags: indefinite-integrals, substitution

I'm interested in understanding the sequence of substitutions needed to obtain
\begin{align}
\int\frac{dx}{\left(a^2+x^2\right) \sqrt{a^2+b^2+x^2}}
=\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{b x}{a \sqrt{a^2+b^2+x^2}}\right)}{a b}\, , 
\end{align}
with $a,b>0$.

The obvious substitution
\begin{align}
x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\tan\xi
\end{align}
gets rid of the square root but complicates the $a^2+x^2$ factor:
\begin{align}
\int\frac{dx}{\left(a^2+x^2\right) \sqrt{a^2+b^2+x^2}}
= \int \frac{d\xi}{ (a^2+ (a^2+b^2)\tan^2\xi)\cos\xi} \tag{1}
\end{align}
which doesn't seem to be immediately helpful.

The substitution $a^2+x^2=b^2\tan^2\xi$ makes things worse since
$dx$ will convert to $b^2 \tan\xi d\xi/(\cos^2\xi\sqrt{b^2\tan^2\xi-a^2})$
with no realistic chance of eliminating the square root.

That would leave me with [Euler's substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution)
\begin{align}
\sqrt{a^2+b^2+x^2}=x+t
\end{align}
but before I get there I wonder if there's a more "obvious" way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first choice is a better start than it seems, because [Bioche's rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioche%27s_rules) advise continuing with$$u=\sin\xi=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\tan\xi}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sec\xi}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+x^2}}.$$Then$$\frac{d\xi}{(a^2+ (a^2+b^2)\tan^2\xi)\cos\xi}=\frac{\cos\xi d\xi}{a^2\cos^2\xi+(a^2+b^2)\sin^2\xi}=\frac{du}{a^2+b^2u^2}.$$

Comment: Beautiful!  That is a neat trick.